# Validate parts of a form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I have a long form on a single page that I split up into parts. I'm using the jquery plugin and I want to validate different parts of it before moving onto the next. Here's my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmuG8/1/)

So after they enter in all their details. I want it to validate it and then if it's good move onto the next page. Then when the next page is filled out, I post all this data. So I made 1 form to contain all that but have two 2 divs in the form to break it up into different pieces.

Problem:
For some reason it won't validate the form even though I click the submit button. Therefore i cannot move onto the next page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined in the console... have you looked into that?

Comment: @Mutmatt O.o odd, i'm not getting that error when I run it on my page. Must be a fiddle thing. and I don't even know what that means to be honest.

Comment: you have too many commas `fname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1,
                lettersonly: true, // <-- you have a lot of these
            },`

Comment: @wirey this can't be the problem, it worked perfectly fine before. It just after this addition of multiple divs in a single form did it break.

Comment: didn't say that was your problem.. but it will definitely break in IE with all those extra commas

Comment: It would probably be better to split it into separate forms.

Answer (score 1):

You have not correct ids

in script you use  `$("#scroll_form")` but in html you have `<form name="everything" id="everything" action="#" method="post">`

You set click event on not existing form

Comment: I was trying to validate a div...i guess that's not possible. Is there no way to validate different parts of a form piece by piece?

Comment: You can create custom validation(but in this case you should write validation by youself). Docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. Pay attention on AddMethod http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage